# Query Condition for common reference data

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, orm, entity-framework-6

For Entity Framework, I have a set of lookup tables that are standardized.  I'm trying to develop a common routine for these sets of tables only, where the EffectiveDate and EndDate is between today.  If there a common way I can setup the predicate in a dynamic fashion, that I don't have to set this up for each table.

Each lookup implements an interface:

```
public class LookupType : IEffectiveEndDates
{

   public DateTime EffectiveDate { get; set; }

   public DateTime? EndDate { get;set; }

}
```

Can I use this interface in combination with something to define a generic query all method?

Comment: Just for clarification: You want to grab all the data where today falls out between the Effective Date and the End Date, correct?

Comment: Yes, all data using those two fields only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a predicate off the interface and use it in a LINQ statement.

```
var date = DateTime.Now;
Expression<Func<IEffectiveEndDates,bool>> pred = 
    x => x.EffectiveDate <= date && x.EndDate >= date;

var lookups = db.ConcreteLookups.Where(pred).ToList();
```

This works because -

1. The compiler accepts it: `Func` is defined as `Func<in T, out TResult>`, which means that the type parameter for the entity (`T`) is contravariant, so a `Func<IEffectiveEndDates,bool>` can also pass for a `Func<ConcreteLookup,bool>`.
2. The query provider successfully translates the expression into SQL, because all property expressions have the right names.

Comment: I think you need to flip the signs. Shouldn't it be `x.EffectiveDate <= date && x.EndDate >= date`?